# Impala Date to String Conversion

Tags: date, hive, type-conversion, impala

How to check the type of a column in impala? Query is

```
select TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Also I want to format the result of the query as a string `yyyyMMdd`. `CAST` returns `null`. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get exactly your question on "check the type of a column". TO_DATE function is returning the result as string.

For your 2nd question, you can use current_date to get the server date then use a function called "DATE_FORMAT".  By the way, Unix timestamp is useful if you want up to hours, mins, seconds and micro seconds and current_date function is sufficient if there is no time required.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd');
Result: 20180316
```

Comment: According to the [Impala SQL reference]https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html), this function is named `FROM_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try below query in impala.

```
Case1:-
    select cast(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd')) as string);
    Result
    2018-03-16

Case2:-
    select cast((FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyyMMdd')) as string);
    Result
    20180316

Case3:-
    select cast(regexp_replace(TO_DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')),'-','')as string);
    Result
    20180316
```

You can use regexp_replace to replace all the **-** with **empty string** so that we can have yyyyMMdd format.

Answer (score 1):

Hi use the following script

```
select from_timestamp('2020-01-01','yyyy-MM-dd')
```